# How do I find the number of fridays between two dates(including both the dates)

Tags: python-3.x

How can i find the *number of days* and also *number of Fridays* between two dates 
inHow can i find the *number of days* and also *number of Fridays* between two dates 
in python. python.

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself yet to solve this?

Comment: I know that there is date and time and calendar module in python , can someone guide me how to use python documentation ,I am beginning to learn python.

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of days between two dates:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_input('Enter date in format yyyy,mm,dd : '), '%Y,%m,%d')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_input('Enter date in format yyyy,mm,dd:'), '%Y,%m,%d')
diff = end-start
print diff.days
>> 361
```

Getting number of Fridays:

```
# key 0 would be Monday as the start date is from Monday
days = {
    0: 0,
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
}
full_weeks = (diff.days) / 7
remainder = (diff.days) % 7
first_day = start.weekday()  # Start date is on Monday
for day in days.keys():
    days[day] = full_weeks
for i in range(0, remainder):
    days[(first_day + i) % 7] += 1
print days[4]  # Gives number of Fridays between the date range
>> 2
```

Python docs - Datetime: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: the Program works but i want user to input the dates so     import datetime
x=input ("Enter date in format yyyy,mm,dd : ")
y=input("Enter date in format yyyy,mm,dd: ")
start = datetime.date(x)
end = datetime.date(y)
diff = end-start
print diff.days   this does not work

Comment: Check the edited answer. Using raw_input to get string and strptime to format it in the desired manner.